# Как Устанавить ChatterBot

Tags: python, pip

я не могу установить `ChatterBot` на пайтоне выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR: Some build dependencies for preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz conflict with the backend dependencies: wheel==0.40.0 is incompatible with wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```